# Scheduling Tasks in Spring

Tags: java, spring, guava, spring-scheduled

We have a requirement where we have to collect documents for X minutes in the database where X could be 30-60. Once these documents are collected in the Database, we have to push them to a separate service over a REST call.

Since these documents won't be very large we aggregate them together and then push them together.

Now, these documents have to be pushed after a fixed interval, So I thought of creating a separate thread which pulls records from the database, pushes them to the service and once the service responds with 200 OK, I remove these records from the Database and the thread goes to Sleep for X minutes.

```
class PushDocumentsToService extends Thread{
    DocumentRepository documentRepository;
    DocumentProcessingService documentProcessingService
    public void run(){
        List<Document> list = documentRepository.getAllDocuments();
        Integer statusCode = documentProcessingService.sendDocuments(list);
        if(statusCode == 200)
            documentRepository.remove(list);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(30*60);
        }catch(..){..}
    }    

}
```

Now a few of my colleagues have advised me against using Thread.sleep in my code. I am not able to understand the ill-effects of

> Thread.sleep()

Also what methods do libraries and frameworks as Spring Scheduler and Google Guava use for Scheduling task?

Comment: Then you should have asked them :)

Comment: I did, they didn't sound convincing, So I wanted to understand the pros and cons of using Thread.sleep()

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do here is use `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule a thread and provide proper frequency rate like this.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledThreadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);    

Thread t1= new PushDocumentsToService();    
scheduledThreadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(t1, 0, 30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: The `PushDocumentsToService` class should probably change to implement `Runnable` instead. Threading is already done by the executor so doing this is confusing.

Comment: @Jai agreed. Your suggestion is precise, i thought of this but later jump to a conclusion of not changing existing design.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Spring Scheduling library in your classpath, add the [`@Scheduled` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html) to the method you wish to execute over a period of time.  No need to extend `Thread` or implement `Runnable`; this is all taken care of on your behalf through Spring.

You know, for as long as the application is *running*.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "30 * * * * *")
public void loadDataIntoRepository() {
    // your code
}
```

It is *ill* advised to use `Thread.sleep` for this for several reasons:

- The thread executing your code **is now *blocked*** for the duration of the sleep period.  30 minutes is a ***very*** long period of time to have your thread blocked.
- Your thread could be interrupted, offering you no real way to recover from your error state.
- You don't want to have to reinvent the wheel with scheduling when that functionality *already* exists and is already well-tested, for maintainability's sake.

Comment: Just curious, what exactly is bad when a thread is blocked for very long period of time? Also, if the `Thread` instance is hidden inside (i.e. private field) a class, then would the interrupt issue be of no concern?

Comment: @makoto I understand I'll be reinventing the wheel but just out of curiosity Doesn't Spring Scheduler too uses Thread.sleep internally or does it use some other native methods?

Comment: @Apurv:  It probably *does*, but regardless of what it uses, that is an implementation detail and not something we need to worry about at this level.

Comment: @Apurv:  When a thread is blocked, it means that no processing can happen until that thread has unblocked itself.  If that thread is holding on to a resource, no other thread can use that resource until it's released.  It can lead to circumstances of deadlock (or livelock), neither of which is desirable or conducive to having a smooth running application.